# Firebase Crash Reporting automatically upload mapping from Android Studios Generate Signed Apk

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, firebase-crash-reporting

I just implemented Firebase Crash Reporting but I don't feel like uploading the mapping file manually every time. So I want to do this automatically. I followed the documentation, but this results in a script I would have to call. I don't have any fancy release script with passwords etc, so currently I make a release with Android Studios build option: "Generate Signed Apk...". Is there a way the upload the mapping after I used this option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/android#uploading_proguard_mapping_files_with_gradle) suggests that you can use a plugin and upload your release APK mappings with a Gradle task:

```
./gradlew :app:firebaseUploadReleaseProguardMapping
```

Please be sure to read the documentation carefully, as there is some setup with service accounts that you need to perform before uploading anything this way.

Comment: Yeah I got that, but how can I automattically run that task after I create a singed apk using the "Generate Signed Apk..." option?

Comment: That task will both build the APK and upload it.  You don't need to manually create it in Android Studio.

Comment: But it never askes for the passwords I use for my keystore

Comment: It's not going to ask.  You have to follow the instructions to get a service account file that authenticates your request to upload the mappings.  That service account effectively acts as your username and password for that particular project.

Comment: A signed apk would need my keystore and it's passwords right?

Comment: You can set that up in build.gradle.  Everything gets a lot faster and easier if you configure for automation.  https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#signing

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Crash Reporting is now deprecated, now they suggest to Upgrade to Crashlytics instead, now that I'm looking for a method that automagically upload the mapping.txt file, I've found this:

> To let Crashlytics automatically upload the ProGuard or DexGuard mapping file, remove this line from the config file:
>
> -printmapping mapping.txt

Hope this can helpo somebody else

[See documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports)